# App UI operations (setting alpha, setting margins, etc.) very slow on 4.4.4 compared to 4.0.3

Tags: android

I have a seekbar that changes the alpha of an ImageView. This works very smooth on an old HTC Desire 200 with android 4.0.3. I tried to run the same code on a Motorola Moto G 2014 that has android 4.4.4. The Motorola phone is 3 times more powerfull than the HTC, but when I use the seekbar the application stutters.

The problem is not with the phone, in the Antutu benchmark the Motorola phone got 18000 points, while the HTC got 6000 points.

Here is the seekbar change event:

```
    int counter = 0;
    private void mainSeekBarProgreessChanges(SeekBar seekBar, int progress) {
        float a = progress / 100f;
        imgRight.setAlpha(a);

        ++counter;
        txtMsg.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }
```

The stutter only appears with bigger pictures (1280x720 or bigger).With small pictures there is no stutter.

There is also stutter when I set the margins of a view with the seekbar.

Here is the manifest of the app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testprog1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testprog1.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_footer"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/start_image_left" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/start_image_right" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="100" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_line1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_msg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE:
If I disable hardware acceleration in the manifest then the performance somewhat improves, but there is still noticeable stutter.

UPDATE 2:
Here is a screenshot when I set the margin of the ImageViews with the seekbar:
[image: When setting margins]

And here is a screenshot where I set the alpha of the ImageViews with setImageAlpha:
[image]

And here is the code that is called in the seekbar change event that sets the margins:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamLeft = (LayoutParams) layoutLeft.getLayoutParams();
layoutParamLeft.setMargins(layoutParamLeft.leftMargin, layoutParamLeft.topMargin, seekBar.getMax() - progress, layoutParamLeft.bottomMargin);
layoutLeft.setLayoutParams(layoutParamLeft);
layoutLeft.invalidate();

FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamRight = (LayoutParams) layoutRight.getLayoutParams();
layoutParamRight.setMargins(progress, layoutParamRight.topMargin, layoutParamRight.rightMargin, layoutParamRight.bottomMargin);
layoutRight.setLayoutParams(layoutParamRight);
layoutRight.invalidate();
```

Comment: The [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(float)) state that one should override `hasOverlappingRendering` to return `false` when using `setAlpha` for performance reasons. Might be worth a shot.

Comment: @Stefan: the problem is that I have overlapping rendering: there are two images on each other, and with the seekbar I change the alpha of the image that is on top. And the stutter also appears when I set the margins of the view with a seekbar. So the problem is not related only to setAlpha, it's a more global problem.

Comment: @Stefan: I override the hasOverlappingRendering property, but there was no performance improvement

Comment: You should enable "Settings --> Developer Options --> Enable GPU Profiling"... then post screenshots of what the result looks like.

Answer (score 3):

It's well known that there are performance problems related to `setAlpha()`. See for example:

- [The proper use of `View.setAlpha()`](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325418001), a G+ post by Roman Nurik.
- [Android Graphics Performance](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha%28int%29) (around the 29:50 mark), a Google I/O 2013 talk by Chet Haase and Romain Guy.

Since it's an `ImageView` widget, Have you tried using [`setImageAlpha()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageAlpha%28int%29) (API level 16+) instead?

Testing your example in a Nexus 5 (with Android 5.0) I get:

- `setAlpha()` -- ~45ms
- `setImageAlpha()` -- ~5ms

but no noticeable stutter either way (and moving the SeekBar is completely smooth).

Comment: I tried using setImageAlpha() but there was no difference, the lag is still there. I don't think the problem is with setting the alpha, the problem is somewhere higher in the chain, since every UI operation is laggy, not just setting the alpha: there is lag when I set the margins using the seekbar, and there is lag when I drag a zoomed image in a TouchImageView. All this works perfectly on a much slower phone.

Comment: @kovacslorand That's weird, updated post with my own results (admittedly a different device and Android version, but the difference is extreme). Is there nothing else in your layout? Background? What are the dimensions of the two images?

Comment: After I disabled hardware acceleration I got better results at the for cycle test, around 400. And if I run the app without debugging then I get the same values on both phones(around 15), but on the slower phone there is no stutter while on the faster phone there is still stutter. So I think that the for cycle test is not relevant anymore to my problem. The images are 1280x720. With small images there is no stutter, only with larger images. Maybe the stutter is because the motorola phone has a screen with a much higher resolution, so there are more pixels to transform?

Comment: The fact that you need to disable hardware acceleration in order to get better performance means that there is definitely something wrong with your code... you should enable GPU profiling and post screenshots of what the result looks like (this will help us understand what is causing the lag). I also **strongly** recommend using Systrace as that tool is the only true way to get a detailed understanding of what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

My use case was to fade out a view's background.  I kept a reference to the view's background drawable and use its `Drawable.setAlpha()` method.

This proves to quite rapid on my reference phone (Galaxy S3) versus using `View.setAlpha(0-1)`, which is slow as balls, and `ImageView.setImageAlpha(0-255)`, which didn't appear to have any effect.

Comment: I see the same results, setImageAlpha is much faster. Also, +1 for using the phrase "slow as balls"

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna let you know there is an answer for this question:

```
ViewCompat.setLayerType(view, LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
```

Ref: [Setting view alpha in runtime is slow, how to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601314/setting-view-alpha-in-runtime-is-slow-how-to-speed-it-up?noredirect=1#comment62688185_37601314)

All credit belongs to Nikola Despotoski